# SwiftUI - Shape causes reverse array access

Tags: swiftui

Trying to understand why using a `Shape` within a `ForEach` would cause reverse iteration of the array. Example:

```
var body: some View {
   ForEach(0...10,id:\.self) { index in
      TestShape()
   }
}

struct TestShape:Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path()
    }
}
```

If you examine `index` with each pass, it would start with 10 and work backwards. However, if instead of calling `TestShape` you instead had say `Text("test")`, index would start at 0 and work its way up. So the key difference here is in the call to a shape. Why is this happening?

Comment: "If you examine index with each pass" how did you examine it?

Comment: Break point or print statement.

Comment: Hmm well don't worry about this, just let `ForEach` do its own thing. The order in which it loops shouldn't affect your code (and if it does, you're probably doing something wrong)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my question. My question is to seek to understand this behavior.

Comment: Aight, but anyway most of SwiftUI's inner behavior is a mystery. It's closed source so we pretty much can only guess.

Comment: Maybe that will be the answer but was thinking there might be an actual explanation that I was just not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

this is the test I used to show that index is not reversed:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

 struct TestShape:Shape {
     func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
         return Path()
     }
 }

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...10,id:\.self) { index in
           let _ = print("---> index: \(index)")
           TestShape()
        }
    }
}
```

output is:

---> index: 0

---> index: 1

---> index: 2

---> index: 3

---> index: 4

---> index: 5

---> index: 6

---> index: 7

---> index: 8

---> index: 9

---> index: 10